# Есть ли плагин на python который при выделение текста задает пробелы всему тексту (Vscode)

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я скопировал код и хочу вставить в else, ну как я вставляю сбиваются пробелы и приходится вручную по коду пройтись и поставить пробелы каждому.
Нету ли плагина vscode который автоматический поставит эти пробелы, а то там 1000 строк кода и это очень долго будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плагин называется так - Paste and Indent

описание плагина:
Если вы обнаружите, что VS Code не делает хорошую работу при вставки кода, попробуйте это расширение. Это позволит вам назначить действие "Вставить и indent" для любого ключевого ярлыка. Эта команда сделает все возможное, чтобы indent код правильно после вставки его (в соответствует окружающий код). Для этого я использую ярлык "Command-Shift-V".